# Inserting huge number of data into sqlite database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-database

i am following this link [using database](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)

but it uses "ContentValues" to insert data into database

```
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
 values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); // Contact Name
 values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber()); // Contact Phone`..
```

but i have 654 number of items to insert..   
therefore i need to write these lines 654 times..is there any alternative way to do this...

Comment: Where do you have these contacts stored? In an array, or in a file?

Comment: I have the values in a json array..

Answer (score -3, accepted):

try like this

 create 2 Arraylist for name and number. Add all the names and numbers using for loop
like this

```
 arralistname.add(contact.getName());
 arralistnumber.add(contactgetPhoneNumber());
```

then use for loop to insert

```
 for(int i=0;i<arralistname.size();i++)
 {
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
 values.put(KEY_NAME,arralistname.get(i)); // Contact Name
 values.put(KEY_PH_NO,arralistnumber.get(i)); // C

 db.insert(tablename,values,null,null);

 }
```

Comment: I have the values in a json array.

Comment: how come my answer isn't ok?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you to use [DatabaseUtils.InsertHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.InsertHelper.html).

Read [this](http://www.outofwhatbox.com/blog/2010/12/android-using-databaseutils-inserthelper-for-faster-insertions-into-sqlite-database/) for more info and example.

As the author assures:

> After replacing SQLiteDatabase.insert with DatabaseUtils.InsertHelper, the database insertion speed went from the equivalent of about 95 rows per second to about 525 rows per second.

Answer (score 1):

the best thing to optimize the speed of making a lot of operations to the DB is using transactions for batch operations.

also, even if it takes a short time to execute, consider putting the operation in the background, while the user sees a progressBar or something.

example:

```
db.beginTransaction();
try{
 for(Contact contact : contacts)
   {
   ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
   values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName()); 
   values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber()); 
   db.insert(tablename,values,null,null);
   }
 db.setTransactionSuccessful();// marks a commit
}
finally{
 db.endTransaction();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The question is not about how to insert values into database.

It seems you have some data you wish to insert into a database. If the items are in a list of some sort then the answers given here would work. If you have the items in a file then you would need to read the file and parse the items and add them into the database. You should not write the same code 654 times.